# Displaying Field's Name from the Array of Objects in an Angular

Tags: angular

Need to display only the Column Name's containing in each row of an array

Eg: From the console

```
this.GobalTableDataSets
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {centerName: "--", batchName: "MentorSchedule_5D5C", scheduleStartDate: "20-Nov-2019 14:38:17", scheduleEndDate: "20-Dec-2019 14:38:17", …}
1: {centerName: "--", batchName: "MentorSchedule_2657", scheduleStartDate: "20-Nov-2019 10:29:46", scheduleEndDate: "20-Dec-2019 10:29:46", …}
2: {centerName: "--", batchName: "Enroll_cf845bd8-43", scheduleStartDate: "18-Jul-2019 18:32:00", scheduleEndDate: "31-Jul-2019 21:28:00", …}
length: 3
```

**component.ts**

```
this._liveDashboardService.getBatchDetails(orgReqDetailsEx ).subscribe(response => {
   if (response !== null && response.length > 0 && response !== null) {
          this.batchDetails = response;
   }
});
```

**Expected Result:**

```
this.GobalTableDataSets[0].<someFunction>
"centerName"
"batchName"
"scheduleStartDate"
"scheduleEndDate"
```

***Here the requirement is to console only the Column Name's (all or particular name) containing from an above array of each row, but not necessarily displaying/fetching Column Values containing those respective Column Name's from an array***

Are there any built-in functions from Angular to accomplish the above scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
let keys = Object.keys(this.batchDetails[0]);
console.log(keys);
```

Working example:

```js
var list = [
{centerName: "--", batchName: "MentorSchedule_5D5C", scheduleStartDate: "20-Nov-2019 14:38:17", scheduleEndDate: "20-Dec-2019 14:38:17"},{centerName: "--", batchName: "MentorSchedule_2657", scheduleStartDate: "20-Nov-2019 10:29:46", scheduleEndDate: "20-Dec-2019 10:29:46"}
,{centerName: "--", batchName: "Enroll_cf845bd8-43", scheduleStartDate: "18-Jul-2019 18:32:00", scheduleEndDate: "31-Jul-2019 21:28:00"}
];

console.log(Object.keys(list[0]));
```

Comment: It worked same as the old school vanilla JS. Is it possible to achieve the same via Angular?

Answer (score 0):

use below code:

component.ts

```
var keys;
this._liveDashboardService.getBatchDetails(orgReqDetailsEx ).subscribe(response => {
   if (response !== null && response.length > 0 && response !== null) {
          this.batchDetails = response;
          keys = Object.keys(this.batchDetails[0])
          console.log(keys);
   }
});
```